# How to implement sleep/wait function without async function

Tags: javascript, promise

for example i got one variable which will be updated after finishing ajax request.

Is there another way to implement it without using async function?
How to implement "wait" function in es5,es6?

```js
let a = false;

setTimeout(()=>{
    a = true;
},10000);
  
(async function(){
  while(!a)
  {
    await new Promise(resolve=>{setTimeout(()=>{
      resolve('pause');
    },5)})  
  }
  console.log(a);
}(a))
```

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do? Right now you're in a tight loop spewing new timeouts as fast as they can be generated. In general you just stop doing things until your timeout ends and use a callback.

Comment: Babel-polyfill dependence weight a lot

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Javascript is single-threaded, so if you implement a sleep feature you’d be blocking every other script from running.

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Explain your higher level issue in more detail

Comment: @charlietfl in one class of my application exist one property. Some time the value of this property setted either asynchronously or not. Im calling this property in another class and i need to check if(property == null) wait();

Comment: Almost always the proper way to do async programming is to do it the way it's intended--don't busy-wait, use a callback or promise.

Comment: You can write every `async function` as a normal function that uses promise chaining with good ol' `then()` calls. For a loop you will just need recursive calls.